# Google Datastore very slow from PHP AppEngine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-app-engine-php

I'm accessing the Google Cloud Datastore from my PHP App Engine instance using the official [google-cloud-php](http://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/cloud-datastore/v1.3.0/datastore/datastoreclient) library.

I'm consistently seeing **upwards of 0.35 seconds of latency per query**. Even for simple queries with less than 100 entities in the datastore.

My web app needs to make 4 or so consecutive datastore queries per request which makes datastore entirely unusable (consistently 1.5 to 3 seconds of latency per page load)

Am I missing something?

---

**Here's how I connect to the datastore:**

```
        // Same issue even without 'authCache' (a memcached wrapper).
        $authCache = new DatastoreAuthCache();
        $datastore = new DatastoreClient([
            'projectId' => AppIdentityService::getApplicationId(),
            'authCache' => $authCache
        ]);
        Datastore::$ds = $datastore;
```

---

**Here are two examples of my queries:**

```
    // Lookup by keys.
    $ds = Datastore::get();
    $queryResults = $ds->lookupBatch($keys);
    $rows = keyValue($queryResults, "found");

    // Query by fields.
    $query = $ds->query()
        ->kind(self::EntityName)
        ->filter('owner', '=', $a)
        ->filter('target', '=', $b)
        ->limit(1)
        ->keysOnly();

    $results = $ds->runQuery($query);
    foreach ($results as $entity) {
        return $entity;
    }
```

Is this level of latency to be expected? I can cache some results, but not all, so I'm hoping this is an issue on my end.

Here's what I've already tried to improve the latency:

- Added 'authCache' handler to cache datastore API tokens (no impact)
- Confirmed datastore and app engine instance are in the same region
- Confirmed that index.yaml is set up correctly
- Confirmed that latency is due to datastore calls and not business logic
- Other database backends are working fine (Cloud SQL server returns in < 0.1 seconds). The local datastore emulator also returns in <0.01 seconds.

What can I do to improve this latency?

Comment: Can't really answer if the latency is to be expected, but perhaps one solution to make it at least feel faster is to move your query code to an AJAX call. That way, the rest of your page could load faster, and then you'd just be waiting on the data. Maybe this just shifts the problem, but I figured I'd offer it if you like.

Comment: Well this could have many reasons... is there a way we can see and inspect your project live?

Comment: The service is a mobile app backend so unfortunately I don't think there's an easy way to do that

Comment: I also tried using the 'keyFilePath' param to load service account credentials instead of application default credentials and my queries are still taking ~0.6s each

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this qualifies as an answer but I'll try to help you debug it using Stack Driver.

Take a look at your logs in the Cloud Console - https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer

Look for the slow handler.

[image: gae_log_message]

Hover over the latency column and click.  This will take you to the distributed tracing system in Stack Driver monitoring.  It's possible this will confirm that Datastore is slow but hopefully it will shed some light on something else that's causing the slowness.

It will look something like this:

[image: stack_driver_tracing]

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about this! I'm seeing about a hundred /remote_socket.Connect .Receive and .Poll entries -- is that normal? .Poll seems to be the problem method here as it's causing the bulk of the datastore latency. Here's a screenshot: https://prnt.sc/n1x19g

Comment: I’ve seen this recently on AppEngine when using cURL for REST API calls. which PHP runtime are you using? You might be better switching to the Protobuf API

Answer (score 1):

The biggest bottleneck is establishing a connection with Datastore (which can take upto 200ms this is where the auth cache helps). Unfortunately this is bad news for php because we cannot establish a permanent connection. The Datastore client needs to reconnect on every request.

It gets even more difficult when trying to optimise because it relies heavily on lazy loading. What seems to work best is reusing the same datastore client instance for all requests.

Limiting the amount of filters speed up queries and instead retrieve larger chunks of data which can then be filtered locally. With the use of something like `redis` which can also doubles as a data cache.

Batching updates picked up by a `cron` service can also help in releasing the request quicker. Notifications can be pushed to a `websocket or picked up on a subsequent requests.

You didn't mention it so it is not clear whether you are using [gRPC](https://cloud.google.com/php/grpc), `DatastoreClient` will use `grpc` by default if the module is installed otherwise it falls back to `REST` which is significantly slower in comparison.

To check if you have `grpc` installed:

```
php -m|grep grpc
```

The only other advice I can think of are indexes, but this will only help with large datasets. You should also try testing at another data centre it may be that the one you are at gets congested.